# Test binding of a custom event to a callback function with Backbone and Jasmine

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jasmine

I'm trying to test to make sure a custom event was bound to upon showing of a dialog. Here is my code:

```
    setupListener = function () {
        appEvent.on('some_event', theHandler);
    };

    theHandler = function (responseData) {
        ....
    };

    this.show = function () {
        setupListener();
    };
```

Note: setupListener is a private function. Here's my test code that works:

```
    it('appEvent.on was called', function () {

        spyOn(appEvent, 'on');
        dialogView.show();

        var theHandler = function (responseData) {
        ....
        };

        expect(appEvent.on).toHaveBeenCalled('some_event', theHandler);

    });
```

But now I want to check the "on" function was called with correct parameters:

```
    it('appEvent.on was called with right parameters', function () {

        spyOn(appEvent, 'on');
        dialogView.show();

        var theHandler = function (responseData) {
        ....
        };

        expect(appEvent.on).toHaveBeenCalledWith('some_event', theHandler);

    });
```

But I get the error:

```
Expected spy on to have been called with [ 'some_event', Function ] but actual calls were [ 'some_event', Function ]
```

The problem looks to be with the handler. How do I check the "on" function was called with the handler?

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the handler function like:

`expect(appEvent.on).toHaveBeenCalledWith('some_event', jasmine.any(theHandler));`